# How do I get the TFS check-in ID in my git log?

Tags: git, git-tfs

Currently the only way to view the tfs checkin id is by using the git log command. As any other git users, I have my prettified git log, so I'd like to include the tfs checkin id flag into my git logs.

It would also be a plus if there's a flag I can use for my prettified log to know if a commit is a local git commit or a tfs checkin commit.

Here's my git alias to return the last ten commits:

```
[alias]
ten = log --pretty=format:\"%C(yellow)%h%Creset %ad %C(green)%s %Creset[%an]\" --graph --date=short --no-merges -10
```

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
[alias]
ten = log --pretty=format:\"%C(yellow)%h%Creset %ad %CONDITIONAL(IF %TFSCHECKINID NOT NULL){%C(red)[%TFSCHECKINID]} %C(green)%s %Creset[%an]\" --graph --date=short --no-merges -10
```

It should appear like this:

```
* xxxxxx yyyy-mm-dd [C9999] This is a TFS checkin [Anonymous]
* xxxxxx yyyy-mm-dd This is a local git commit [Anonymous]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to try is adding `--decorate` or the `%d` format placeholder to include the refs that point to the commit. This doesn't mark all the commits, but it will put `tfs/default` on the TFS head, which should make it pretty obvious which of your recent commits aren't from TFS. You might also try `%gd` or `%gD`.

You can also turn on autotagging in your project's [config](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/1cad8c8e119584af2bc198d865fd679bd2149f2d/docs/config.md), and use `%d`.

Comment: that seems like a good start. but if I were to checkout somewhere in the middle and created a branch it would just say `(HEAD, test_branch)` in the first commit.. only once I've rebased from master only it will show `(HEAD, test_branch)` in the first commit, and `(tfs/default, master)` in the second..